# Adding footer view programmatically to view controller

Tags: ios, swift, swift5

I am trying to add a footer view programmatically in the existing view controller by modifying the constraint. But the method I applied for only works on some screen, some of the screens don't show the footer view with the message in console "Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints."

Here is the method I have tried

```
class ViewHandler: NSObject {
    static let shared = ViewHandler()


    let appLogo : UIImageView = {
        let imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "footer-logo"))
        imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        return imageView
    }()

    let companyLogo : UIImageView = {
        let imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "info-logo"))
        imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        return imageView
    }()


    func putView(viewController: UIViewController){
        let myView = UIView()
        myView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        myView.backgroundColor = UIColor(hexString: "#FFFFFF")

        let parentView = viewController.view!

        parentView.addSubview(myView)
        myView.addSubview(appLogo)
        myView.addSubview(companyLogo)


        myView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: parentView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        myView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: parentView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        myView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: parentView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        myView.heightAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualToConstant: 50).isActive = true

        appLogo.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: myView.leadingAnchor, constant: 16).isActive = true
        appLogo.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: myView.topAnchor, constant: 8).isActive = true
        appLogo.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: myView.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: -8).isActive = true

        companyLogo.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: myView.trailingAnchor, constant: -16).isActive = true
        companyLogo.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: myView.topAnchor, constant: 8).isActive = true
        companyLogo.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: myView.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: -8).isActive = true


        for subView in parentView.subviews {
            if subView != myView {

                subView.getBottomConstraints().forEach { (constraint) in
                    if constraint.firstAttribute == .bottom && constraint.secondItem === parentView {
                        print("Constraint ==========> \(constraint)")
                        constraint.isActive = false
                    }

                }


                subView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: myView.topAnchor).isActive = true
            }

        }

        parentView.layoutIfNeeded()

    }
}


extension UIView {
    // retrieves all constraints that mention the view
    func getAllConstraints() -> [NSLayoutConstraint] {

        // array will contain self and all superviews
        var views = [self]

        // get all superviews
        var view = self
        while let superview = view.superview {
            views.append(superview)
            view = superview
        }

        // transform views to constraints and filter only those
        // constraints that include the view itself
        return views.flatMap({ $0.constraints }).filter { constraint in
            return constraint.firstItem as? UIView == self ||
                constraint.secondItem as? UIView == self
        }
    }

    // Example 1: Get all width constraints involving this view
    // We could have multiple constraints involving width, e.g.:
    // - two different width constraints with the exact same value
    // - this view's width equal to another view's width
    // - another view's height equal to this view's width (this view mentioned 2nd)
    func getWidthConstraints() -> [NSLayoutConstraint] {
        return getAllConstraints().filter( {
            ($0.firstAttribute == .width && $0.firstItem as? UIView == self) ||
            ($0.secondAttribute == .width && $0.secondItem as? UIView == self)
        } )
    }

    func getBottomConstraints() -> [NSLayoutConstraint] {
        return getAllConstraints().filter( {
            ($0.firstAttribute == .bottom && $0.firstItem as? UIView == self) ||
            ($0.secondAttribute == .bottom && $0.secondItem as? UIView == self)
        } )
    }

    // Example 2: Change width constraint(s) of this view to a specific value
    // Make sure that we are looking at an equality constraint (not inequality)
    // and that the constraint is not against another view
    func changeWidth(to value: CGFloat) {

        getAllConstraints().filter( {
            $0.firstAttribute == .width &&
                $0.relation == .equal &&
                $0.secondAttribute == .notAnAttribute
        } ).forEach( {$0.constant = value })
    }

    // Example 3: Change leading constraints only where this view is
    // mentioned first. We could also filter leadingMargin, left, or leftMargin
    func changeLeading(to value: CGFloat) {
        getAllConstraints().filter( {
            $0.firstAttribute == .leading &&
                $0.firstItem as? UIView == self
        }).forEach({$0.constant = value})
    }
}
```

This is how I add the footer view

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
     super.viewWillAppear(animated)
     ViewHandler.shared.putView(viewController: self)

}
```

Please help me to fix this issue. If this is not the appropriate way then suggest me the best method to do this. I can add the footer view with the storyboard but I want to do it programmatically.

Comment: which constraints are not being satisfied? it should tell you what constraints are broken and which part has conflicts

Comment: @Joshua it works perfectly for some view controller.. but for some view controller it shows error like this (
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000248e0d0 UILayoutGuide:0x600003e647e0'UIViewSafeAreaLayoutGuide'.bottom == UITableView:0x7fa6aa864e00.bottom   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000024bb9d0 UIView:0x7fa6a9f16ad0.bottom == UIView:0x7fa6ac0bda60.bottom   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000024bba70 UIView:0x7fa6a9f16ad0.height >= 50   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000248d860 UITableView:0x7fa6aa864e00.bottom == UIView:0x7fa6a9f16ad0.top   (active)>"
)

Comment: @Joshua Any solution??? Please

Comment: Do you want your "footer view" to be *at least* 50-pts tall? Or *exactly* 50-pts tall? If *at least*, then what are you using to determine its height? The size of the images you're loading? And, what is your `for subView in parentView.subviews` loop supposed to be doing? It looks like a bad approach to whatever it is...'

Comment: Are you trying to make a floating footer? I'm asking because this sort of code in your question won't be able to be displayed in something like a UICollectionViewController or a UIPageViewController.

Comment: @DonMag I want to make the footer view support for safe area device also... which means the footer view bottom should extend below the safe area i.e super view.. But the image inside the footer view should appear above the safe area.. thats why i made that to at least 50 pts tall.. Help me out with the best approach to do this

Comment: @elliott-io i want to add that footer view below of any view so that it does not block the content of the view controller

Comment: @DeependraDhakal - you should edit your question with a better description of what you're trying to do. Posting only code that "doesn't work on some devices" makes it very difficult to help. Include some screen-caps showing what you *want* to achieve and showing what's happening when it's not working as expected.